# How to send image between React Native and Flask?

Tags: python, firebase, react-native, flask, api-design

I have a React Native app where I want to send an image to my Flask backend to do some image processing (annotations) then return this new image back to React Native to display it.

I spent a whole day trying to figure this out but was unsuccessful. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

I plan on using Firebase's storage system to store these images so I wouldn't mind using that either if that makes things easier.

What I've tried so far is sending the image uri to Flask and read the image file and was able to do the image processing however I couldn't figure out how to send the new image back to React Native...

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the image to Flask right now?
Typically you could implement an async function on RN that awaits a response.

In plain English:
A function that uploads an image to the back end and awaits for the image to be processed.
Expects in return a URL of the image on the back-end (or Firestore).